# Unique values in PyTorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, unique

I'm tying to find distinct values in a PyTorch tensor. Is there an efficient analogue of Tensorflow's [unique op](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique)?

Comment: Just for future reference - there's a feature request for this on pytorch's github, here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2031

Comment: As pointed out in the other answer, [unique op](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.unique) exists in torch>=0.4

Answer (score 20):

There is a [torch.unique()](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.unique) method in 0.4.0

In `torch <= 0.3.1` you can try:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

x = torch.rand((3,3)) * 10
np.unique(x.round().numpy())
```

Comment: Nice.. but unique (0.4.0) is CPU only currently.. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can convert to a numpy array and make use of numpy's built-in `unique` function:

```py
def unique(tensor1d):
    t, idx = np.unique(tensor1d.numpy(), return_inverse=True)
    return torch.from_numpy(t), torch.from_numpy(idx)
```

Example:

```py
t, idx = unique(torch.LongTensor([1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8]))  
# t --> [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
# idx --> [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: I think this will work but I would rather avoid numpy operations as it could take too much time.  
Anyway, I think this is the only solution by now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. get common items between two tensors with `torch.eq()`
2. fetch indices and concatenate tensors
3. finally get common items via `torch.unique`:

```
import torch as pt

a = pt.tensor([1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,6])
b = pt.tensor([7,2,3,2,7,4,9,4,9,8])

equal_data = pt.eq(a, b)
pt.unique(pt.cat([a[equal_data],b[equal_data]]))
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add some explanation along with your code.

Comment: we get common items between two tensors .
Equivalent of  @2 tensor.eq() fetch indices and concatenate tensors finally get common items help of 'torch.unique' .

Comment: a[equal_data].unique() should do the trick too while avoiding the cat ;)